# How to create Wi-Fi hotspot in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: hot-spot

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I have an Ethernet internet connection.

I have connected this cable with my PC directly without using any wifi router. So I want to use my PC as wifi hotspot. Can you tell me how to create Hotspot in ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick I guess: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html

Comment: That is for 15.04 but may work for 12.04.